# Power up while running

Tags: temple-run-2

How do these instant power ups activate?
I am filling up with coins and when full it illuminates.  But does not active the power up.  So how does this work

Answer (score 1):

You need to double tap the screen to activate the powerup. You can use this strategically, for example you can quickly activate a speed or shield boost to avoid crashing into an upcoming obstacle.